Shape and level of swap rate historical volatility VS swaption implied volatility
When comparing realized swap rate volatility and implied ATM swaption volatilities, should one expect the shape across tenors of the implied volatility to be reflected in the realized and their level? Or are these quantities don't speak to each other as much and one should not be surprised to see very different shapes and levels across tenors?
